# Python Beautifulsoup table td element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm able to get the data from the HTML table, but how would I get only the data I need? For example, how would I read only '10 or more sm (16+ km)'? Line 7?

```
KBWI (Baltimore-Washington, MD, US)
KBWI 301254Z 10007KT 10SM SCT017 BKN023 OVC039 21/18 A3027 RMK AO2 SLP249 T02060178
20.6°C ( 69°F)
17.8°C ( 64°F) [RH =  84%]
30.27 inches Hg (1025.1 mb) [Sea level pressure: 1024.9 mb]
from the E (100 degrees) at   8 MPH (7 knots;  3.6 m/s)
10 or more sm (16+ km)
2300 feet AGL
scattered clouds at 1700 feet AGL, broken clouds at 2300 feet AGL, overcast cloud deck at 3900 feet AGL

page = urlopen(metar_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')

for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    metar = tr.find_all('td')[1].text.strip()
    print(metar)
```

Comment: view-source:https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=kbwi&format=decoded&date=&hours=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the data after the `Visibility` span.

So you can do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=kbwi&format=decoded&date=&hours=0"
resp = requests.get(url)

page = soup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

table = page.find('table')
activate_print = ['Visibility:']

save_flag = False
for td in table.find_all('td'):
    if save_flag:
        print(td.text)
        save_flag = False
    if td.find('span') and td.find('span').text in activate_print:
        save_flag = True
```

**result:**

```
10 or more sm (16+ km)
```

Of course if you want something else you just have to do the same logic and add a teg inside the `activate_print` list

Comment: save_flag, what does this do?

Comment: Just a boolean to flag the right `td` you can call it as you wish :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also read it into a dataframe (since it's a `<table>` tag), and filter out that way.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=kbwi&format=decoded&date=&hours=0"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df[df[0] == 'Visibility:'][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with td tag only.

```
print(table.find_all('td')[13].text.strip())
```

Code:

```
page = urlopen(metar_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
print(table.find_all('td')[13].text.strip())
```

---

Or you can find the span tag `Visibility` and then find next td tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=kbwi&format=decoded&date=&hours=0")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
print(table.find('span',text='Visibility:').find_next('td').text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
10 or more sm (16+ km)
```

Answer (score 0):

Succinct way with bs4 4.7.1+ is to use :contains and an adjacent sibling combinator

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=kbwi&format=decoded&date=&hours=0')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('td:contains("Visibility:") + td').text)
```

Comment: I was also trying your method to see, and I noticed that if I do print(soup.select_one('td:contains("Ceiling:") + td').text), it says this object have no .text attribute, but if I do the same for Visiblity, it works.